# Auth cookie invalid after restart AspNetCore 3

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I use cookies authitifiation.
When i reboot server my auth cookie set is invalid, but cookie is end longer.

How to make cookies to be valid after a server reboot?

This is reproduced in `AspNetCore 3.0`

Comment: You will need to [configure data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) so that it can persist the encryption keys. If you launch your app right now, you should see a message in the logs that tells you that it will use an in-memory storage; and of course that will not survive app restarts.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and will say the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@poke 's comment helped me!

> You will need to configure data protection so that it can persist the
>   encryption keys. If you launch your app right now, you should see a
>   message in the logs that tells you that it will use an in-memory
>   storage; and of course that will not survive app restarts.